# Where can i find all ErleCopter simuation files?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi , I want to simuaite ErleCopter :ErleRobotics  , drone , where can i find examples and other people work ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13159/where-can-i-find-all-erlecopter-simuation-files-?/) by [Mrmrzamany](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2570/mrmrzamany/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think you're looking for [these](http://erlerobotics.com/docs/Simulation/Configuring_your_environment.html) tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1